# fetching textarea value and retain back value

Tags: php

The problem is I am not able to retain textarea value back on page
fetch value of the textarea from database but not able to retain its previous value.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="a" rows="3"> </textarea>
```

**PHP:**

```
$_SESSION['b']['page3']=$_POST; FETCHING VALUE IN SESSION

$query = "INSERT INTO `a`(`textarea`) values('".$page3['B']."')";
// inserted properly textarea value in database

// now fetching textarea value

$query  = "SELECT * FROM `a` WHERE `id` = '1'";
$data       = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$result     =mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$textarea1 = $result['textarea'];
```

**Now want to retain textarea value:**

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="texta">
 //CODE FOR RETAINING TEXTAREA VALUE
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['texta']))echo $_SESSION['texta']; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't know where you set `$_SESSION['texta']`. Are you sure it contains what you think it contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming,

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
..
<textarea class="form-control" name="a" rows="3"> </textarea>
..
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// Setting textarea value in session if not empty
if(!empty($_POST['a']))
{
    $_SESSION['texta'] = $_POST['a'];
}

// Inserting to database
..
..
```

**Again HTML:**

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="texta">
<?php 
    if(!empty($_SESSION['texta'])) 
        echo $_SESSION['texta']; 
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: how to unset this session when database entry doesnot exist and i want blank form again????